# Row_number calculation in sql, oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Now i am facing one small issue in sql code.

I have no idea about this logic.

```
with res as (
select 
85,
2,
45,
34,
60,
2,
6,
4,
78,
6,
23,
45,
80,
80

from dual
)
 select * from res
```

I have mention 3 header .1.input  2.Expected  3.Actual.
And my question is set one column based on input days we have to display rn column. IF value is days > 60 them we have to display as zero and next row value will be start as 1 and to printed as 2, 3, 4... till days > 60.then we have to set as 0 for days > 60 and agin start from 1, 2,3 ... still days > 60. its loop till end of value.

```
Input       Expected            Actual  

DAYS        DAYS    RN      DAYS    RN
85          85      0       85      1
4           4       1       4       2
32          32      2       32      3
7           7       3       7   4
5           5       4       5   5
66          66      0       66  6
14          14      1       14  7
25          25      2       25  8
2           2       3       2   9
9           9       4       9   10
70          70      0       70  11
80          80      0       80  12
6           6       1       6   13
3           3       2       3   14
1           1       3       1   15
78         78      0        78  16
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group rows based on column sum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218969/group-rows-based-on-column-sum-value)

Comment: You seem to assume an ORDER to the values in your RES subquery. However, rows have no natural order (even when you WRITE them in a specific order). How do you know the "first" value is 85, the "second" is 4, etc.? Are they ordered by another column, perhaps a "sequence" column, or a date or timestamp column, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

OK, first of all... for meaningful results, you need a way to order the input data to get a row number for each record.  You cannot just rely on each record's position in a list, because that's undefined in Oracle if these records are coming from a table.

So, assuming we add a `rn` column to your `res` table, all you need to do is this:

```
select res.rn, 
       res.days, 
       res.rn - nvl(last_value(case 
                when res.days < 60 then null 
                else res.rn end) ignore nulls over (order by rn),0) lrn
from res;
```

That `nvl(last_value...` expression finds the `rn` (row number) of the most recent input record having `days` >= 60.  So, if a record's `rn` is 15 and the most recent record with `days` >= 60 was 13, then that record gets renumbered as "2".

For this to work, your `rn` values in the input data must start at 1 and have no gaps.  If that is not the case with your real data, then you will need to add another `with` clause before this to do a `dense_rank` or something to get them that way.

Here is a complete example, using your test data (from your expected result):

```
with res (rn, days) as (
select 1, 85 from dual union all
select 2, 4 from dual union all
select 3, 32 from dual union all
select 4, 7 from dual union all
select 5, 5 from dual union all
select 6, 66 from dual union all
select 7, 14 from dual union all
select 8, 25 from dual union all
select 9, 2 from dual union all
select 10, 9 from dual union all
select 11, 70 from dual union all
select 12, 80 from dual union all
select 13, 6 from dual union all
select 14, 3 from dual union all
select 15, 1 from dual union all
select 16, 78 from dual
)
-- Above is just test data.. solution starts here
/* with ... */ 
select res.rn, res.days, res.rn - nvl(last_value(
     case when res.days < 60 then null else res.rn end) 
     ignore nulls over (order by rn),0) lrn
from res
```

> ```
> +----+------+-----+
> | RN | DAYS | LRN |
> +----+------+-----+
> |  1 |   85 |   0 |
> |  2 |    4 |   1 |
> |  3 |   32 |   2 |
> |  4 |    7 |   3 |
> |  5 |    5 |   4 |
> |  6 |   66 |   0 |
> |  7 |   14 |   1 |
> |  8 |   25 |   2 |
> |  9 |    2 |   3 |
> | 10 |    9 |   4 |
> | 11 |   70 |   0 |
> | 12 |   80 |   0 |
> | 13 |    6 |   1 |
> | 14 |    3 |   2 |
> | 15 |    1 |   3 |
> | 16 |   78 |   0 |
> +----+------+-----+
> ```

`LRN` is the "expected" `RN` from your desired results.  For simplicity, I omitted the "actual" columns, which just seemed to be duplicates of the input data.

Answer (score -1):

You don't include your actual select statement.

I'm guessing it is something like this:

```
 select res.*, row_number() OVER () AS RN from res
```

You want to use modulus like this:

```
 select res.*, (row_number() OVER ()) % 5 AS RN from res
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with row_number modulo 4.

Comment: @mathguy I was looking at his example code and expected

Comment: And where did you see anything having to do with modulo 4, either in the example code or in the expected output?

Comment: @mathguy right there in the expect output... now that I look again it is mod 5 and there is one row with 0 twice.   but that is what it looked like to me.